# How to uncheck checkbox on props change in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to uncheck the checkbox, when props changes.

How can I do this ?

This is my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" value={inventory.id}
    defaultChecked={_.some(this.props.cart.data, (cart) => {
                       return cart.id === inventory.id
                   })}
    onClick={(e) => this.addToCart(e, inventory)}/>
```

When I remove data from this.props.cart, checkbox should be unchecked.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try toggling the checked property not the defaultChecked property

```
render: function() {
    return <input type="checkbox" 
                  checked={_.some(this.props.cart.data, (cart) => cart.id === inventory.id)} 
                  onClick={(e) => this.addToCart(e, inventory)}/>
}
```

See the react docs for more examples:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs